# ¿Como reemplazar el método Date.getDate() en android studio?

Tags: java, android, date

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Quiero validar si una fecha es mayor o igual que otra, el problema es que he usado `Date.getDate()` y funciona bien pero me sale ***deprecated*** el método `getDate()` por cual se podría reemplazar, además si es correcto la forma de como
estoy validando las fechas.

Este es mi código

```
String fecha1 = txtFechaDia1.getText().toString();
String fecha2 = txtFechaDia2.getText().toString();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dfecha1 =  sdf.parse(fecha1);
Date dfecha2 = sdf.parse(fecha2);
if (dfecha1.getDate()>=dfecha2.getDate()){
   Toast.makeText(this,"Fecha Inicial no debe ser mayor a la fecha fin",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else {
   Toast.makeText(this,"Todo paso bien checkado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Puedes buscar Java Calendar, o calendar api java Enlace a la API:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html Enlace a ejemplos:
https://mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/ Enlace a Comparar fechas:
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método [getDate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate--) esta marcado como  obsoleto, debes usar la clase [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), ejemplo:

```
        String fecha1 = txtFechaDia1.getText().toString();
        String fecha2 = txtFechaDia2.getText().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dfecha1 =  sdf.parse(fecha1);
        Date dfecha2 = sdf.parse(fecha2);

        //Crea instancias de Calendar
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(dfecha1);
        cal2.setTime(dfecha2);

        //Realiza la comparación de Fecha en milisegundos.
        if (cal1.getTimeInMillis() >= cal2.getTimeInMillis()){
        //if (dfecha1.getDate()>=dfecha2.getDate()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Fecha Inicial no debe ser mayor a la fecha fin",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
           Toast.makeText(this,"Todo paso bien checkado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Incluso puedes también realizar la comparación usando la función [after()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after-java.lang.Object-) :

```
    //Realiza la comparación de Fecha en milisegundos.
    if (cal1.after(cal2)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Fecha Inicial no debe ser mayor a la fecha fin",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
       Toast.makeText(this,"Todo paso bien checkado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

> [after()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after-java.lang.Object-): Devuelve si este calendario representa un tiempo
> posterior al tiempo representado por el objeto especificado.